# Can't get 2 clients to listen to one UDP server

Tags: java, udp, client

I've got an UDP(server) which is receiving data from users does some calculations and sends the new data back, I can for sure tell that the server is receiving the data from the first client as well as from the second but only the first client is receiving the data back
This is my receive method in both clients

```
private void receive(){

         try{
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(2390);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            socket.receive(packet);
            String msg = new String(buffer,0,packet.getLength());
            String[] coor = msg.split(" ");
            x = Integer.parseInt(coor[0]);
            y = Integer.parseInt(coor[1]);
            x1 = Integer.parseInt(coor[2]);
            y1 = Integer.parseInt(coor[3]);
            packet.setLength(buffer.length);
            socket.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

when the second client tries to use this receive method I get an exception:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Game.receive(Game.java:73)
    at Game.<init>(Game.java:58)
    at Game.main(Game.java:92)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the no-arg constructor for the clients `new DatagramSocket();`

> The no-arg constructor is used to create a client that binds to an arbitrary port number. The second constructor is used to create a server that binds to the specific port number, so the clients know how to connect to.

```
private void receive(){

         try{
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            socket.receive(packet);


            String msg = new String(buffer,0,packet.getLength());
            String[] coor = msg.split(" ");
            x = Integer.parseInt(coor[0]);
            y = Integer.parseInt(coor[1]);
            x1 = Integer.parseInt(coor[2]);
            y1 = Integer.parseInt(coor[3]);
            packet.setLength(buffer.length);
            socket.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Also the socket should be created only once so probably not there, I think this `receive` method is in a loop like so...

```
// here is a good place to init the socket
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
while(true){
    //receive();
    receive(socket); //pass the socket if it is a local

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but after removing port I ended up receiving nothing, so I'm still using the port in the constructor and just moved the socket before the while loop and also removed the .close and now it works